# How can I upload a file with windows mobile?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, mobile, file-upload, windows-phone-8

All I have is a simple `<input type='file'/>` and a Windows Phone 8X HTC. In all other devices (iPod, ipad, android), the button is clickable and a file dialog shows up. But when I click it on windows phone - nothing happens. No file dialog at all.

I remember seeing people sending emails with attachments with their windows phones, so I assume that I am doing something wrong.

How can I upload a file on windows phone?

**P.S.** when I went to people whom I saw sending attachments with their phone, I found that they used native app, not html...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 doesn't support this directly from the browser (apparently, it might if you have an expansion card/memory card in the phone, but I don't have one to test with). I can say that the current developer preview of Windows Phone 8.1 does support it. When you click a file upload button in IE11 on WP8.1, a file selector is shown.

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that every phone below 8.1 was not able to upload any file to internet? This is so amazing :-(

Comment: Correct, only with a native app (or like I said, maybe with an SD card).